# 2011 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I am working with the candidates to find a time that allows the most participation.

(**Candidates**: candidates on other sites have reported that my email has been placed in their spam folder. Please be on the lookout for an email from me!)

Here are the details so far:

- I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the election phase, so I am looking at the 22nd-24th.  As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates, I will edit this post with details on the "when".
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=wordpress.stackexchange.com).
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidate regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, the transcript of the event will be permanently linked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, based on the availability of the participants, there isn't a time that would work even for a majority of candidates.

There will not be a scheduled town hall chat - if you have questions for the candidates, they can absolutely be asked here on the meta site.

I guess y'all will have good moderator coverage no matter who is elected.  (:

Good luck to the candidates!